# PyInstaller - ImportError: No module named 'rethinkdb'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, rethinkdb-python

I compile using `pyinstaller -F ./parser.spec`.
Then I run the program with `./dist/parser` and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'rethinkdb'
parser returned -1
```

I tried to create a hook file, but to be honest I really feel like I have no idea what I'm doing.

`rethinkdb` is in `hiddenimports` but `pyparser` doesn't throw any errors at me indicating what might be wrong.

parser

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
...
import rethinkdb
...
```

parser.spec

```
...
a = Analysis(
    ['parser'],
    pathex=[os.path.realpath('./env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/')],
    binaries=None,
    datas=added_files,
    hiddenimports=['rethinkdb'],
    hookspath=[os.path.realpath('./hooks')],
    runtime_hooks=None,
    excludes=None,
    win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
    win_private_assemblies=None,
    cipher=block_cipher
)
...
```

hooks/hook-rethinkdb.py

```
hiddenimports = [
    'ssl',
    'cPickle',
    'pickle',
    'itertools',
    'multiprocessing',
    'builtins',
    'rethinkdb',
    'rethinkdb.ast',
    'rethinkdb.errors',
    'rethinkdb.net',
    'rethinkdb.ql2_pb2',
    'rethinkdb.query',
    'rethinkdb.version',
]
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `pyinstaller`?

Comment: I bundle the application as a standalone command line program that can be placed in `/usr/local/bin` without dependencies. Some people in the company cannot and should not be expected to know about git, python, virtualenvs, etc...

Comment: @dalanmiller, on a related issue, why is the `python-driver` for `rethinkdb` not on github? I think I've figured out the issue. I'd like to fork the driver and fix the problem, but since the driver is not on github, I guess I'll have to create a new repo.

Comment: Totally understood @demux and completely 100% agree. It is actually on Github! But it's nested in the RethinkDB repo => https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/tree/next/drivers/python. Also, if you're on Slack, we have a #driver-dev channel if you need assistance => http://slack.rethinkdb.com.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same kind of trouble with an application I was making but it had an easy fix.  I am not sure if it will work for you but I would at least try it because it is really easy.  Instead of editing the spec file try running this in the command line:

```
pyinstaller --paths=C:/Users/.../Python34/Lib/site-packages filename.py
```

Obviously change the path to the correct path for your computer.  Hopefully this helps if not I hope you can find an answer.

Comment: Thank you, but this will not do. the python path of my virtual environment is already in the `.spec` file, even though it doesn't need to be there. All other packages get included. It's just rethinkdb that is missing.